# How can I fix the blank page problem in php?

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error, cpanel

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');?>
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
    $currDir = dirname(__FILE__);
    include("{$currDir}/defaultLang.php");
    include("{$currDir}/language.php");
    include("{$currDir}/lib.php");

    $x = new DataList;
    $x->TableTitle = $Translation['homepage'];
    $tablesPerRow = 2;
    $arrTables = getTableList();

    // according to provided GET parameters, either log out, show login form (possibly with a failed login message), or show homepage
    if(isset($_GET['signOut'])){
        logOutUser();
        redirect("index.php?signIn=1");
    }elseif(isset($_GET['loginFailed']) || isset($_GET['signIn'])){
        if(!headers_sent() && isset($_GET['loginFailed'])) header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
        include("{$currDir}/login.php");
    }else{
        include("{$currDir}/main.php");
    }?>
```

I ran the above code and I got a blank page in return, I also have error reporting turned on but still, I cannot find any errors please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236), [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Unless in one of the `include()` is an `echo` statement, you have no output, resulting in a blank page. Try `echo 'Hello';` and see if it displays.

Comment: You need to show us the contents of either main or login files.

Answer (score 0):

pls am Fred from Ghana and I had the same problem as you have now. I have resolve my problem and would like to share with you. I used mysql as the database of my web app. When I lunch local host phpmyadmin,I have to type my username and password before I can login and see my database. So what I did to resolve the problem was,after login in ,I went to General settings, change password and I selected no password radio button and clicked on go button beneath and I reopened local host phpmyadmin without password. That was all. Try it and it works 100%.